# Memory leaking from object that I do not alloc

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have the following function, which results in `*timeString` leaking memory.  I am fairly new to Objective-C (and memory management), but I read that you only need to `release` objects that you `alloc` in the first place.  Because I `alloc` `*formatter`, and then set that to `*timeString`, does this mean that I  now have to release `*timeString` too?

Here's the code:

```
-(NSString *)getDate{

    NSLog(@"getDate");

    NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    NSString *timeString;

    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [formatter release];

    return timeString;
}
```

---

EDIT:  Here is where the `getDate` function is called:

```
-(NSString *)getFileName{

    //nameofXMLFile = page_##
    NSString *nameOfFile = [NSString stringWithString:pageTitle];

    //nameOfXMLFile = page_##.DataCheckSheet.xml
    nameOfFile = [nameOfFile stringByAppendingString: @".DataCheckSheet.xml"];

    NSString *dateString = [self getDate];
    dateString = [dateString stringByAppendingString: @"_"];

    NSLog(@"datestring: %@", dateString);

    dateString = [dateString stringByAppendingString:nameOfFile];

    NSLog(@"datestring with append: %@", dateString);

    //nameOfXMLFile = yyyy-MM-dd_page_##.DataCheckSheet.xml
    nameOfFile = dateString;

    return nameOfFile;
}
```

Comment: No, you've got that right...you shouldn't have to release timeString...though, allow me to ask: What are you doing with that TimeString? I mean, you're returning it, which means you're probably using it somewhere. Are you sure, there isn't a retain or something along the way?

Comment: It gets returned to another function, and then appended to some other strings.  I will edit that code into the question so you can take a look.

Comment: What also comes to mind: You're not using threads, right? Because if you did, you'd need to create a separate AutoReleasePool for it.

Comment: I don't know what threads are :) ... So no I don't think I am using them.  I've edited in some more code.

Comment: Do you have an autorelease pool?

Comment: I have an autorelease pool in my main method... I started with some apple sample code and that was part of it, I haven't been autoreleasing anything though.

Comment: Well, I may see a bit of an issue. You're assigning 'dateString', which should still be autoreleased, to 'nameOfFile' (overwriting that content) and return that. So essentially, you're still passing the first variable along. Where does 'nameOfFile' go?

Comment: `nameOfFile` get returned to another method, and then assigned to a string: NSString `*nameOfXMLFile = [self getFileName];`

Comment: Still no retains, anywhere in sight? Because so far, I've seen nothing, which could explain that behaviour...

Comment: In reference to your first comment, if I return an object from a method, and then assign it something, and that something is not released, does that mean that the original object that was returned from the method is also not released ?

Comment: Well, technically, when you assign something, you overwrite the original pointer and the object is 'lost'...a.k.a. should be released. If it's used to construct the other object though, and that new object is not released, I could imagine, the original object not getting release either.

Comment: @ATaylor I found my problem, there was indeed a `retain` further down the line, and releasing that object seems to have done the trick.  If you wanna put an answer together saying something about `retain` I will give you the check mark

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`.

Answer (score 1):

As you already correctly stated, all objects, that aren't explicitly alloced, are per definition 'autoreleased', which means they will be destroyed, once they leave the scope of the function that defined them.

To keep an object valid longer than that, for example, by keeping it around as a class object, you would call 'retain' on it.
This 'retain' needs to 'released', just like an 'alloced' object.

By passing the reference to the object in question as return value, the scope of the object gets expanded to the function, which called the function in the first place...which means, the object would be destroyed at the end of the calling function, unless it is retained by then.

nameOfFile is still that very object in question, since you copied the address of dateString to that variable, effectively erasing that string from existence (it will thereby get autoreleased).
Try to avoid such assignments, unless you have a reason for them, to avoid confusion.

In short: If you have a chain of function calls and returns, make sure, that there isn't a 'retain' somewhere along the line, which doesn't get released appropriately, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to understand leaks is to use Instruments and its "Leaks" template.

The "leak" instrument will show you what objects are leaked and you will be able to jump right away to the ObjectAlloc instrument to see retain/releases calls to the leaked object. You should then be able to find where missing release(s) are.

As is, your code looks OK wrt memory management. However most of the strings created here are autoreleased, which means they will be effectively released when the outter autorelease pool will be drained. Until the pool is drained, your object might appear to leak.

In typical applications, the main thread has an autorelease pool automatically installed by NSApplication/UIApplication, yet the pool is drained only when the application receives events (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874726/nstableview-reloaddata-leaking-memory/11880403#comment15820198_11880403))

In a usual detached thread (using NSThread or pthread), you have to install your own pool(s) (and drain them regularly).

GCD dispatch queues install their own autorelease pool and drain them from time to time.